# Error While running project "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexguardDebug'."

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, dexguard

Both IDE and Project Encoding is set to UTF-8. What else is missing. 
Here is Error details

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexguardDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\Android Projects\aa\app\build\intermediates\res\resources-debug.ap_(;;;;;;!**/*~,!/LICENSE,!***/./**,!**/picasa.ini,!/META-INF/NOTICE,!**/.svn/**,!**/.*,!***/_/**,!/LICENSE.txt,!**/SCCS/**,!/META-INF/LICENCE,!/NOTICE.txt,!**/about.html,!**/thumbs.db,!/META-INF/LICENSE.txt,!/NOTICE,!**/CVS/**,!**/package.html,!/META-INF/NOTICE.txt,!**/overview.html,!org/w3c/dom/*,!org/w3c/dom/ls/*,!org/xml/sax/**,!org/xmlpull/v1/**,!org/json/JSON*,!org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class,org/apache/http/Consts.class,org/apache/http/HttpHeaders.class,org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.class,org/apache/http/util/Args.class,org/apache/http/util/Asserts.class,org/apache/http/util/CharsetUtils.class,org/apache/http/util/NetUtils.class,org/apache/http/util/TextUtils.class,!org/apache/http/*,!org/apache/http/auth/*,!org/apache/http/auth/params/*,!org/apache/http/client/*,!org/apache/http/client/entity/*,!org/apache/http/client/methods/*,!org/apache/http/client/params/*,!org/apache/http/client/protocol/*,!org/apache/http/client/utils/*Utils.class,!org/apache/http/conn/*,!org/apache/http/conn/params/*,!org/apache/http/conn/routing/*,!org/apache/http/conn/scheme/*,!org/apache/http/conn/ssl/*,!org/apache/http/conn/util/*,!org/apache/http/cookie/*,!org/apache/http/cookie/params/*,!org/apache/http/entity/*,!org/apache/http/impl/*,!org/apache/http/impl/auth/*,!org/apache/http/impl/client/*,!org/apache/http/impl/conn/*,!org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/*,!org/apache/http/impl/cookie/*,!org/apache/http/impl/entity/*,!org/apache/http/impl/io/*,!org/apache/http/io/*,!org/apache/http/message/*,!org/apache/http/params/*,!org/apache/http/protocol/*,!org/apache/http/util/*,com/guardsquare/dexguard/runtime/***,!com/guardsquare/**,!**/dexguard.pro,!lib/*dictionary*.txt,!com/saikoa/**.properties,!proguard/**.properties,META-INF/services/**,!META-INF/**,!.hg**,!**/.hg**,!.git**,!**/.git**,!.svn**,!**/.svn**,!CVS,!CVS/**,!**/CVS,!**/CVS/**,!.cvsignore,!**/.cvsignore,!SCCS,!SCCS/**,!**/SCCS,!**/SCCS/**,!**.orig,!**~,**.class,lib/*/*.so,res/raw/*.so,assets/**.so,!**.so,!.readme,!**.keep,!**.DS_Store,!**.aidl,!**.rs,!**.rsh,!**.d,!**.java,!**.scala,!**.scc,!**.swp,!**.bak,!**thumbs.db,!**picasa.ini,!**package.html,!**overview.html,!**.AIDL,!**.RS,!**.RSH,!**.D,!**.JAVA,!**.SCALA,!**.SCC,!**.SWP,!**.BAK,!**THUMBS.DB,!**PICASA.INI,!**PACKAGE.HTML,!**OVERVIEW.HTML)] (Can't process XML file [AndroidManifest.xml]: file appears to be in binary XML format. Please check if you have included a default DexGuard application configuration. (Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.))

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you include the wrong default configuration. DexGuard offers two distinct set of default configurations: for application project and library projects.

You need to make sure that you include the right one, e.g. dexguard-release.pro if building an application, or dexguard-library-release.pro if building a library.